# Generate averages and standard deviation in csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, average

I would like to take this [CSV](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/25e3625c5674fae04c46a7dabc0c11d1/cpu-7day.csv), and do the following:

1 - Divide the data into blocks of 60 elements, where each new block it moves 10 elements

*Example: 0 to 60, 10 to 70, 20 to 80 ... etc*

2 - Then divide the blocks into 5 parts (12x5 = 60)

3 - Calculate [average](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-statistics-mean-function/) and [deviation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-statistics-stdev/#:%7E:text=Statistics%20module%20in%20Python%20provides,rather%20than%20an%20entire%20population.) of each part

4 - Take the next 30 elements from each block of 60 elements

*Example: 60 to 90, 70 to 100, 80 to 110 ... etc*

5 - Calculate how many readings there are from 0 to 100, grouping every 20

*Example: 0 to 20, 20 to 40, 40 to 60, 60 to 80 and 80 to 100*

> (0 to 20) 12,18,11,14 = 4
> (20 to 40) 20,25,23 = 3
> ...

The result would be a dataframe like this:

---

```
mean 1 | standard deviation 1 | ... | mean 5 | standard deviation 5 | 0 to 20| 20 to 40 | ... | 80 to 100
```

---

My code performs this process, but something is failing in the path and returning me from the final output 336 lines, but based on my data it was supposed to be around 700 lines. In addition, I would like to make this code cleaner, to improve interpretation, any suggestion?

```
def standardDeviation(data):
    """ Calculates standard deviation """
    
    return statistics.stdev(data)
       
def average(data):
    """ Calculates average """
    
    return statistics.mean(data)

def captureOcurrences(elements, n):
    """ Capture an X number of elements within a list """
    
    return [elements[i: i+n] for i in range(0, len(elements), n)]

def neuronsInput(elements):
    """ Generates input neuron modeling (5 averages, 5 standard deviations - Between 12 occurrences in a window of 60 readings) """
    
    result = []
    temp = []
    start = 0
    limit = 60
    size = int(len(elements))
    TargetDivision = int(size / 30)
    repetitions = 0
    five = 0

    while repetitions < TargetDivision:
        temp = []

        five += 1
        ocurrences = captureOcurrences(elements[start: limit],12)
        for i in ocurrences:
            m = average(i)
            sd = standardDeviation(i)
            temp.append([m,sd])

        result.append(temp)

        repetitions += 1
        limit += 10
        start += 10

    return result

def neuronsOutput(elements):
    """ Generates output neuron modeling (Histogram of the next 30 data readings) """
    
    result = []
    start = 61
    limit = 90
    size = int(len(elements))
    TargetDivision = int(size / 30)
    repetitions = 0

    while repetitions < TargetDivision:

        counter=collections.Counter(elements[start: limit])
        
        consumption0_20 = 0
        consumption20_40 = 0
        consumption40_60 = 0
        consumption60_80 = 0
        consumption80_100 = 0
        for key in counter:
            if key <= 20:
                consumption0_20 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 20 and key < 40:
                consumption20_40 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 40 and key < 60:
                consumption40_60 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 60 and key < 80:
                consumption60_80 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 80 and key < 100:
                consumption80_100 += int(counter[key])

        result.append([consumption0_20,consumption20_40,consumption40_60,consumption60_80,consumption80_100])

        repetitions += 1
        limit += 10
        start += 10

    return result
```

### Example Data

```py
data = {0: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:00', '"cpu"': 27.6},
        1: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:01', '"cpu"': 0.7},
        2: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:02', '"cpu"': 1.0},
        3: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:03', '"cpu"': 2.7},
        4: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:04', '"cpu"': 0.9},
        5: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:05', '"cpu"': 4.2},
        6: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:06', '"cpu"': 1.1},
        7: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:07', '"cpu"': 0.6},
        8: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:08', '"cpu"': 3.0},
        9: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:09', '"cpu"': 0.8},
        10: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:10', '"cpu"': 3.7},
        11: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:11', '"cpu"': 13.2},
        12: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:12', '"cpu"': 1.3},
        13: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:13', '"cpu"': 2.9},
        14: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:14', '"cpu"': 11.7},
        15: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:15', '"cpu"': 9.2},
        16: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:16', '"cpu"': 1.1},
        17: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:17', '"cpu"': 0.7},
        18: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:18', '"cpu"': 4.1},
        19: {'data': '7/11/2020 0:19', '"cpu"': 0.7}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using `NumPy` for such operations (This is much faster rather than using `for` loops in the code). You could do it simply using `NumPy` as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#read the data
df = pd.read_csv('cpu-7day.csv')
data = df['"cpu"'].values

#task 1
blocks_data = []
for i in np.arange(0, int(data.shape[0]-50), 10):
    blocks_data.append(data[i:i+60])
blocks_data = np.array(blocks_data)

#task 2
parts_data = blocks_data.reshape(-1, 5, 12)

#task 3
mean_parts_data = np.mean(parts_data, axis = -1)
std_parts_data = np.std(parts_data, axis = -1, ddof = 1)

#task 4
next_data = []
for i in np.arange(60, int(data.shape[0]-20), 10):
    next_data.append(data[i:i+30])
next_data = np.array(next_data)

#task 5
count_groups = np.array([np.sum(((0<=next_data) & (next_data<20))*1, axis = -1),
                         np.sum(((20<=next_data) & (next_data<40))*1, axis = -1),
                         np.sum(((40<=next_data) & (next_data<60))*1, axis = -1),
                         np.sum(((60<=next_data) & (next_data<80))*1, axis = -1),
                         np.sum(((80<=next_data) & (next_data<100))*1, axis = -1)]).T

#collect all and merge in new dataframe
mean_std = np.append(mean_parts_data.reshape(-1, 1), std_parts_data.reshape(-1, 1), axis = -1).reshape(-1, 10)
pad_count_groups = np.pad(count_groups, (0, mean_std.shape[0]-count_groups.shape[0]))[:, :5]
res_data = np.append(mean_std, pad_count_groups, axis = 1)

columns = ['mean_1', 'std_1', 'mean_2', 'std_2', 'mean_3', 'std_3', 'mean_4', 'std_4', 'mean_5', 'std_5',
           '0_20', '20_40', '40_60', '60_80', '80_100']
myDF = pd.DataFrame(res_data, columns = columns)

#save this dataframe
myDF.to_csv('myDF.csv', index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Divide the data into blocks of 60 elements, where each new block it moves 10 elements"

Have you accounted for the decreasing length of the final 6 size60 blocks?

Ex:

```
#extract elements from testInputData & write to blocks [0,30),[10,40),[20,50)......
testInputData = list(range(0, 100))
data = [[]]
activeBlockIndexes=[]
i = 0
for row in testInputData:
    if i%10==0:
        activeBlockIndexes.append(int(i/10))
        data.append([])
    for b in activeBlockIndexes[-3:]:
        data[b].append(row)
    i+=1
for row in data:
    print('['+('{:>4d}'*len(row)).format(*row)+']')
```

```
[   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29]
[  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39]
[  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49]
[  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59]
[  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69]
[  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79]
[  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89]
[  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99]
[  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99]
[  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99]
```

Comment: I didn't notice it, what do you suggest?

Comment: I need to maintain the logic for assembling a neural network

Comment: can you help me with this please?